# Finding a twin prime in binary expansion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Numbers from 1 to 63 are placed on 6 cards according to the following 6 rules:

1. The 1st digit in the binary expansion of each number on card 1 is a one.
2. The 2nd digit in the binary expansion of each number on card 2 is a one.
3. The 3rd digit in the binary expansion of each number on card 3 is a one.
4. The 4th digit in the binary expansion of each number on card 4 is a one.
5. The 5th digit in the binary expansion of each number on card 5 is a one.
6. The 6th digit in the binary expansion of each number on card 6 is a one.

A twin prime appears on cards 2, 3, and 4 but not on cards 1, 5, and 6.
Even though the amount of numbers printed on each card is unknown it is still possible to find the number. What is the number?

Note:the 1st digit in the binary expansion appears in the rightmost position
while the 6th digit in the binary expansion appears in the leftmost position.

My attempt: I was thinking that the only number that appears on cards 2,3 and 4 and not on the rest was 14 which is 1110, but this isn't twin prime so I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Please clarify whether we are to assume each number 1 to 63 appears on one and only one of the six cards.  This was my impression from the opening sentence of your post, but this is not supported by your last paragraph, which seems to presume a number may well appear on more than one card.

Comment: @hardmath: The opening sentence is ambiguous. The final paragraph of the question makes clear that a number may appear on more than one card.

Comment: I'm now thinking that "What is the number?" refers to the twin prime and not "the amount of numbers printed on each card".

Comment: @hardmath: Yes, that's correct. But now I understand your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> The $n$th digit in the binary expansion of each number on card $n$ is
>   a one

is not equivalent to

> If the $n$th digit in the binary expansion of a number is a one, then
>   the number is on card $n$.

This subtle distinction is what tripped you up; just because a number *can* appear on a card, does not necessarily mean it *is* on that card. In other words, absence gives us no information.

We will use $?$ for unknown digits. Since the prime appears on cards $2$, $3$, and $4$, it must look like:
$$??111?$$
Since a binary number ending in $0$ is even and there are no even primes but $2$, we have:
$$??1111$$

Can you take it from here?